# Sharepoint 2013 Community portal showing "There are currently no communities in this view"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a community portal site and a couple of community sites. But I keep on getting "There are currently no communities in this view." on the community portal. I tried to re-index the search and did full crawl and it didn't help. The test for the query inside the content search webpart (webtemplate:community) is not returning result at all. 
Is there any step I need to perform after creating the community sites so that the search crawls these sites?

Comment: You'd probably do better asking on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

it is about search service application indexes. Set crawling rules and content via Central Administration --> Manage service applications --> Search Service Applications. Then reset the index and re-crawl.